# What does slower handling mean?

Tags: far-cry-3

I have a multiplayer weapon mod that has the text "Longer range and improved accuracy. Slower handling".
What does the Slower handling mean?

Comment: I believe most LMG have a lower handling skill, which probably refers to the movement speed while the weapon is equipped

Answer (score 3):

A slower handling means that it takes longer to:

- Enter aim mode
- Shoot after going out of cover
- Shoot when in sprint mode
- Shoot after switching to the weapon

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure 'slower handling' refers to slower iron sights, weapon switch, and reloading.